# view not updated after the url change

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, vuejs3

I'm trying to access users of different users using my search input where I can type the name of the user and then click on any of the result and navigate to their page. The first user page is displayed but when I search for another user and click on the user name then the route gets updated in the address bar but the view in the window still displays the earlier user. what am I doing wrong in my code?

```
<template>
  <div>
    <custom-component :users="users" @input="onClick"></custom-component>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
 methods: {
    onClick(id) {
      this.$router.push(`/user/${id}`);
    },
 },
 watch: {
    $route(to, from) {
      if (to.params.id !== from.params.id) {
        this.$router.push(to.fullPath);
      }
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change watch and fetch the users list again. No need to push the router again in watch.

```
watch: {
  $route(to, from) {
    // react to route changes...
    let self = this;
    self.getUsers(); // For example
  }
},
```

Comment: what is that getUsers() function? don't see that in my code

Comment: Its just an example

Comment: How you pass property users to the sub component. You need to repeat that in watch

Comment: it still didn't change the view.

Comment: The created hook is called once so on route change you need to apply the code again to change the property users

Comment: so anything should call initiate the created hook? even doing a console.log?

Comment: Can you send me complete code how you pass property users?

Comment: No created hook can't be called again but you need to move your code to a method. call that method in created and in watch.

Comment: If you can provide me the code that would be easy to explain.

Comment: the users array came from a parent component. it was a graphql apollo query. ```apollo: {
    users: {
      query: GetUsers,
    },
  },```

Comment: i receive it as a prop in my component

Comment: You need to fetch this gql query in a method. Call that method inside created and watch.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231329/discussion-between-shahidiqbal-and-helpmepiliizzz).